# Perl subroutine is not updating/refreshing text interface with toggle button

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I am very new to perl, and I am creating a grid button interface in which it involves fetching data of current SSID network connected. I am not getting any error, but it is not refreshing the current information.

Here is what I have tried, but it does not update mw.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;
use Tk::LabFrame;
use Tk::widgets qw(LabFrame);
use POSIX;

my $mw= tkinit;

my $gridOrPack="grid";
my $tpFrame=$mw->LabFrame(-label=>'Info');
my $code_font = $mw->fontCreate(-family => 'arial', -size => 10);

if ($gridOrPack=~/grid/i) {
  $tpFrame->grid(-row=>1, -column=>1, -sticky=>'nsew');
  $mw->gridRowconfigure( 1, -weight => 1 );
  $mw->gridColumnconfigure( 1, -weight => 1 );
}
else {
  $tpFrame->pack(-side=>'top',-expand=>1,-fill=>'both');
}

my @buttons;
my $text1 = qx(Netsh WLAN show interface | grep -w  SSID | perl -pne s/.*?:.//);
chomp($text1);

push @buttons, $tpFrame->Label(-text=>  "Network  :   " .$text1." ",-font => ['arial', '10'],-justify => 'left')->pack(-side=>'left')
->grid
($tpFrame->Button(-text => 'Refresh Info', -bg => 'yellow', -width => 11, -height => 3, -command => sub { toggle(\$text1) }, -font => $code_font ));


MainLoop;

sub toggle {
    my $text_ref = shift;
    $$text_ref = qx(Netsh WLAN show interface | grep -w  SSID | perl -pne s/.*?:.//);
    chomp($$text_ref);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-textvariable` option of `Tk::Label`. This connects the widgets text property with a perl variable to automatically reflect its content.

```
push @buttons, $tpFrame->Label(-textvariable=>  \$text1,
                               -font => ['arial', '10'],
                               -justify => 'left')->pack(-side=>'left')
```

etc.

Comment: Missing the `"Network  : ` prefix, but you get the point. Add it to your qx line if needed.

Comment: Nice :) textvariable made it very minimalistic.. modified the qx line as well to fit my needs.. thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The Tk::Label object doesn't have a *reference* to `$text1`. It merely has a *copy* of `$text1`'s original data. Changing `$text1` later won't change what the label says.

You'll need to keep the Tk::Label object in a variable somewhere, then call Tk::Label's `configure` method to update the text.

Do something like this:

```perl
my $label = $tpFrame->Label(
  -text     => "Network: $text1",
  -font     => [ 'arial', '10' ],
  -justify  => 'left',
);
push @buttons, $label->pack(-side=>'left')->grid(
  $tpFrame->Button(
    -text     => 'Refresh Info',
    -bg       => 'yellow',
    -width    => 11,
    -height   => 3,
    -command  => sub { toggle( \$text1, $label ) },
    -font     => $code_font,
  )
);

MainLoop;

sub toggle {
  my ( $text_ref, $label ) = @_;
  $$text_ref = qx(Netsh WLAN show interface | grep -w  SSID | perl -pne s/.*?:.//);
  chomp($$text_ref);
  $label->configure( -text=> "Network: $text1" );
  return;
}
```

Comment: I just added ;     on the my $label (.....); and now it is perfectly working! Thank you checking for your great suggestion.

Comment: Added the missing semicolon to my answer. You may also be interested in @clamp's answer which approaches the "the label doesn't have a reference to `$text1`" issue from the other direction, and gives the label a reference to `$text1`.